# Trying to create an efficient infinite looping frame animation routine for Android

Tags: android, graphics, android-animation

Since AnimationDrawable's memory blows up after a few images, I needed to write my own.  Google has some demonstrations regarding efficient frame animations, but it is very complicated(needlessly?).

Here is my initial approach, can I get some experts/smart ppl to chime in?

1. Create a Handler on the UI Thread.
2. create runables (A) for the handler.
3. inside the runables (A), I create AsyncTasks for each frame.
4. each AsyncTask is run using PostDelay to achieve desired frame rate.
5. the target ImageVew is set wigh the new frame from the AsyncTask.

Here is the code:

```
private void addTask(Handler handler, final String animationName, final int frameNumber, final AsyncTaskLoadBitmap asyncLoadBitmap, int frameIndex) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int frameIdentifier = getResources().getIdentifier(animationName, "drawable", getPackageName());
            Log.v("Runable","adding name");
            new AsyncTaskLoadBitmap(imageView,thisActivity).execute(frameIdentifier);
        }
    };

    boolean done =  handler.postDelayed(runnable,100 + (100 * frameIndex));
    Log.v("PostDelayed","Done");
}
```

The problem I'm having is making it loop and a way to stopping the loop.

What could be a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    setContentView(iv);

    final int LOAD = 1;
    final int SHOW = 2;
    HandlerThread loader = new HandlerThread("frameLoader");
    loader.start();
    Callback callback = new Callback() {
        int idx = 0;
        int[] ids = {
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.layer0, R.drawable.layer1, 
        };
        Resources res = getResources();
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == LOAD) {
                Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage LOAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                idx++;
                if (idx < 18) {
                    Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, ids[idx % ids.length]);
                    msg = mUIHandler.obtainMessage(SHOW, btm);
                    mUIHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            } else
            if (msg.what == SHOW) {
                Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage SHOW " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                iv.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) msg.obj);
                mBackgroundHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(LOAD, 500);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(loader.getLooper(), callback);
    mUIHandler = new Handler(callback);

    mBackgroundHandler.sendEmptyMessage(LOAD);
```