# Handler from a different thread is not receiving message from main thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I believe I'm not understanding how Handler can pass/receive messages.

I have a handler created on a different thread, and then have the main thread send it a message.  Here is how I did it

```
 public void startAniHandlerThread(int timer){
    final int sleeptime = timer;
    int test2;
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){

            Looper.prepare();
            Log.v("loop","looping");
            Handler handler = new Handler(){
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
                    Log.v("Thread handler", "checking");
                    if(inputMessage.what == 10) {
                        if (inputMessage.arg1 == 2) {

                            Log.v("Thread handler", "stop");
                        } else if (inputMessage.arg1 == 1) {
                            Log.v("Thread handler", "continue");
                        } else{
                            Log.v("nothing", "nothing");
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            Looper.loop();
        }
    };


    thread1.start();
}
```

Here is how I attempted to send a message to it from the UI thread:

```
public void stopAniHandlerThread(){
    Handler newHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    Runnable newRunable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Message message = new Message();
            message.what = 10;
            message.arg1 = 2;
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    };
    newHandler.postDelayed(newRunable, 2000);
}
```

Here is the Log I get(I'm expected this to get called, but it doesn't:

```
 Log.v("Thread handler", "stop");
```

> V/stopAniHandlerThread﹕ posting 
>   V/loop﹕looping

Comment: why don't you use a HandlerThread?

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729245/trying-to-create-an-efficient-infinite-looping-frame-animation-routine-for-andro you have a sample use of it

Comment: Is too incomplete for me to use, I'd have to figure out like 10 things before I can tryout the code, I'm not at that level where I can just know what the code does in a round about way yet

Comment: what is too incomplete? i don't understand your comment at all,  you have a working piece of code, so why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I'm not sure what sample you are talking about, my sample or yours? Either one of those I'm not sure how that helps me to figure out what I did wrong here.

Comment: so in a nutshell: 1) create a HandlerThread,  2) start() it,  3) create a Handler with HandlerThread's Looper, thats it, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729245/trying-to-create-an-efficient-infinite-looping-frame-animation-routine-for-andro